# Trying to post a question

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I am trying to post a question and am getting a message:

"Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above."

But there is no error indicated. Is there a glitch, or am I missing something.

Thanks.

JUST NOW: Went out of se and back in - was asked to copy some script to veryify if I was a human (was one last time I checked) and was able to post.

Comment: I also got a "cannot post your comment" yesterday.  Fixed by leaving and returning to se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have JavaScript enabled, and that you're not blocking 3rd-party scripts (if MathJax is rendering properly on the site, you should be fine).

Also make sure you look off to the right a bit - some errors are now displayed in the right sidebar:

[image: tag error]

If this happens again, please specify the browser + version and OS you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Regards, Andrew

Comment: As of yesterday, the sidebar fades when such an error message is shown, so hopefully it's harder to miss now.